# Alfresco ScriptNode function getAspectsShort is missing/undefined

Tags: alfresco

First of all, I am running V4.2.e Community Edition.
I have the following webscript/free marker template(ftl) to retrieve aspects from a certain node,

```
[
  <#list node.aspects as aspect>
    ${jsonUtils.toJSONString(aspect)}<#if aspect_has_next>, </#if>
  </#list>
]
```

with the following js part:

```
var docid = url.extension;
model.node = search.findNode(docid);
```

It works perfectly. It returns something like:

```
[
  "http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}titled"
]
```

but I want:

```
[
  "cm:titled"
]
```

In the following ScriptNode API I found a similar function called "`getAspectsShort`":
[Alfresco Community 4.2 Documentation - Script Node](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.community.doc%2Freferences%2FAPI-JS-ScriptNode.html)

Obviously there are backend functions in the java classes:
[ScriptNode.java](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2e/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.java)

My tried to use it in the following way:

```
[
  <#list node.getAspectsShort as aspect>
    ${jsonUtils.toJSONString(aspect)}<#if aspect_has_next>, </#if>
  </#list>
]
```

and found the following message in the catalina.out:

`Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TemplateException: 011933961 Fehler bei der Verarbeitung der Mustervorlage 'Expression node.getAspectsShort is undefined on line 2, column 12 in aspe
ct.get.json.ftl.'. Bitte wenden Sie sich an Ihren Systemadministrator.
        at org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:222)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.renderTemplate(AbstractWebScript.java:896)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(DeclarativeWebScript.java:267)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:147)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression node.getAspectsShort is undefined on line 2, column 12 in aspect.get.json.ftl.
        at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
        at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:100)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
        at org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:218)
        ... 31 more`

Any help will be appreciated,
Oliver

Comment: [Alfresco Java API Reference](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you're referring to the JavaScript API but you're using the Freemarker objects to retrieve data. So not all the JavaScript methods are implemented in Freemarker.

So use the node.aspectsShort in your JavaScript controller and pass the value to the model object to the Freemarker template.

Here is the reference wiki of the [Template node API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Template_Guide#TemplateNode_Model_API)
And the reference in the [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/topic/com.alfresco.community.doc/references/API-FreeMarker-TemplateNode.html)

Comment: You are right. Thanks. It works also perfectly in the javascript console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shortQName

```
${shortQName(jsonUtils.toJSONString(aspect))}
```

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2FAPI-JS-Utility-shortQName.html